# Single page or Step-by-step form. Which is the better approach for a trained user?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, usability-testing

I am working on a form where the employee (user) takes customer feedback and fills it in a form.
This form has currently lot of fields (30-35). Logically this form can be broken down and grouped into different sections.

**Should I break the form down into steps or should I keep it all in the same page given that the user is trained and would be using this form regularly?**

Also, if it should be step by step how can I test if it is actually slowing down the process?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95422/keep-long-form-or-separate-into-multiple-steps/95432#95432). The participants in the experiment were novice, but I think you can still get nice information for the advantages and disadvantages between the 2 approaches.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov, That was a good read, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify.

Your user is the **employee** and according to you, he/she is trained. That makes the the answer simple.

**Do not break down the form**.

The user interacting with the form will be doing it numerous times in a single day and continuously stepping forward (or backward in case some customer changes their views) would be a hassle to say the least.

Keep the layout clean and have ample spacing between each form field but keep it in a single page so that the employee can simple use the *type n' tab* action to fill out the form

Comment: Is there a way to test both the approaches?

Comment: Thanks for your answer though it makes lot of sense.

Comment: @Rockyp - If you want to test it out then you will need a trial run. Maybe an A B testing. But I am just being logical here. The reason we break down huge forms is to not intimidate the user. If your user is already aware of the length of form and is using it on a regular basis, that logic goes out the window

Answer (score 0):

If this is a central tool in the employees' daily workflow, my approach would be to test both solutions on a number of people, probably around 5 - 6 subjects per solution.

In terms of determining which is faster, this will be as straightforward as starting and stopping a stopwatch, but depending on the fidelity of your prototype, conducting a formal test would allow you to identify usability pros and cons to either solution that are maybe not as obvious as time spent. For example, imagine the single-page solution is 30 seconds faster on average, but the test users generally express annoyance with a loss of overview. Would this be justified by a relatively small temporal advantage?

This conclusion is made from the assumption that this is a tool that will be used often by the employees. If this is indeed the case, overall UX should be taken very seriously, and conclusions shouldn't be made on assumptions of prior knowledge.

Comment: What I feel is having multiple steps may give me better results in terms of usablity & experience initially but it will become annoying when the user has to run it all day through.

Comment: Testing also can be challenging here as the step by step process can have lot of scenarios. For ex. customer may wants to update some of the previous form etc. so going back and forth can also be a problem. Thoughts?

Comment: It is obviously not possible to test for every scenario, but I would assume you could fairly include a task in your task script that asks the subject to go back and change a previously submitted answer. I agree with you that the multiple steps solution seems more user-friendly at a first glance, and this is why I would prioritize finding out whether or not the single-page solution is that much quicker that it justifies sacrificing UX (if multiple steps even is the better UX, which testing will also help determine). Hope this helps

Comment: A-B testing can easily be wrong in this case. Where single-page is arguably better is with repetition. Judging on a few impressions is going to be inaccurate, even with sophisticated users.